# Unusual behavior binding 3rd party Bootstrap themed jQuery control using Aurelia CLI

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I'm using the [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in my Aurelia CLI app and it seems to be working for the most part with one quirk.

Here is my code:

```
import {Question} from "../../wizard/question";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as datetimepicker from "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker";

export class DateTimePicker {
    associatedQuestion: Question;
    picker;   

    activate(model) {
        this.associatedQuestion = model;
    }

    attached() {
        console.log(datetimepicker);
        $(this.picker).datetimepicker();
    }
}
```

And my component's html:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Label -->
        <label for.bind="associatedQuestion.id" innerhtml.bind="associatedQuestion.label"></label>

        <!-- Edit Display -->
        <div class="input-group date" ref="picker">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id.bind="associatedQuestion.id" value.bind="myvalue" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>

        <!-- Review Display -->
        <div if.bind="associatedQuestion.displayMode == 'review'">
            ${associatedQuestion.value}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And here's an excerpt from my `aurelia.json` required for this control:

```
  {
    "name":"jquery",
    "path":"../node_modules/jquery/dist",
    "main":"jquery.min",
    "export": "$"
  },
  {
    "name": "bootstrap",
    "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
    "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
    "deps": ["jquery"],
    "resources": [
      "./css/bootstrap.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker",
    "path": "../bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build",
    "main": "js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min",
    "resources": [
      "./css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
    ]
  }
```

**Note the line** `console.log(datetimepicker);` **in the code.**

Without this line I receive the error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
    at DateTimePicker.attached (http://localhost:9000/scripts/app-bundle.js:591:28)
    at Controller.attached (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:22088:24)
    .
    ..
    ...
```

I'm unsure what I'm experiencing here. I anticipate I'm missing something simple or just plain doing it wrong, but I'm stumped.

I'd also like to note that I'm basing this off of [this Github issue](https://github.com/aurelia/documentation/issues/193) which I understand may or may not be the preferred way to handle this one year on.

Comment: show your aurelia.json

Comment: @FabioLuz added what I thought pertinent, is there anything else you'd like to see?

Comment: I should also note I'm using Aurelia CLI 0.26.1 for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that in your aurelia.json you're using `"export": "$"` when the correct syntax is `"exports": "$"`, but I don't think it will change anything.

Nevertheless, here are some things you can try:

**Attempt 1**

Considering that `eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker` exports a function, this should work in theory:

```
attached() {
  datetimepicker($(this.picker)); //or maybe $(this.picker)[0];
}
```

**Attempt 2**

Although `eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker` supports modular systems (apparently), `bootstrap` doesn't. The easiest way to handle bootstrap and jquery plugins is using `<script>` tags or appending them into the bundle. So, this will certainly work:

```
"prepend": [
  "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
  "node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resources/scripts/configure-bluebird.js",
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
  "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
]
```

Afterwards, remove jquery, bootstrap and detepicker from `dependencies` and all their import statements from .ts files.

Finally, use jquery, bootstrap and datepicker as global functions:

```
attached() {
  $(this.picker).datetimepicker();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, **Attempt 1** results in: `Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
    at a.fn.datetimepicker (http://localhost:9000/scripts/vendor-bundle.js:28216:2729)`

Comment: As for **Attempt 2**, I'm unfamiliar with how to make `$` globally accessible. When I remove the references from `dependencies` and remove their import statements from .ts files, Gulp  complains: `error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.` Also, how do I reference the .css files previously bundled within `resources`?

Comment: I apologize if I missed some obvious things here. I've now thoroughly read [the 'Adding Client Libraries to Your Project' documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/10) and a number of related Stack Overflow issues am not seeing how to make `$` and `datatimepicker` available to my component when using the prepend bundling method. Nor am I seeing how to bundle and reference their related `.css` files since I can't `<link>` to the `bower_components` or `node_modules` directories.

Comment: The `$` and `datetimepicker` are available to your component. What you are getting is a typescript error. To fix the error just put this file https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/index.d.ts inside the `custom-typings` folder (copy and paste manually)

Comment: To load the css files, unfortunately you will have to use `<link>` tags in this case. What you could do is loading from CDN, which is even faster https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/. Or perhaps you could try to remove `bootstrap` from `prepend` and put it into the `bundles`, which should work fine. (only bootstrap into the `bundles`, jquery and datepicker remain in `prepend`)

Comment: If you don't want to use CDN, you can export your css files using `copyFiles` feature. See http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/10

Comment: Using CDN for whatever I can is preferred, so that's perfect. I've done as instructed, Bootstrap is loading via CDN, jQuery and 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker' are loading via `prepend`, and jQuery and 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker` typings are installed. But when I run I recieve the message `File not found or not accessible: C:/src/choiceswizard/src/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker.js. Requested by C:/src/choiceswizard/src/resources/elements/controls/datetimepicker/datetimepicker.js`.

Comment: I thought perhaps this meant I didn't need the line `import * as datetimepicker from "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker";`, but when I remove that TS complains despite having installed [https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker). And if I try to use `EonasdanBootstrapDatetimepicker` without the import statement I receive the message from TS: `'EonasdanBootstrapDatetimepicker' refers to a UMD global but the current file is a module. Consider using an import instead.`

Comment: Oh I see, this is a typescript error. Copy this type definition file https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.d.ts to the `custom-typings` folder

Comment: I don't appear to have a `custom-typings` folder. Where does it belong? And does this mean that running something like `npm install @types/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker` is not sufficient for installing typings for certain definitions?

Comment: Also, do I save the file as `custom-typings/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.d.ts` since `index.d.ts` is a rather generic name. And does this mean I'll refer it as `EonasdanBootstrapDatetimepicker` within my code since that is the name that is the definition has defined as `export as namespace EonasdanBootstrapDatetimepicker;`? If it's not obvious I'm a little new to TypeScript and all this definition file stuff.

Comment: I've since come across [this site](https://kristianmandrup.gitbooks.io/aurelia-app-amazement/content/project-structure.html) describing project structure and noted the `custom_typings` folder in the root of the project. Created the structure `/custom-typings/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.d.ts` and in my code I have `import * as dtp from "../../../../../custom-typings/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker";`.

Comment: you don't have to import custom-typings... it will just tell TS that the function `datetimepicker()` exists. There's something wrong in your project. Try creating a new project, add jquery/bootstrap/datetimepicker/ and see if the problem still occurs

Comment: Okay, so I think I've got this worked out, and you're a saint for sticking with me. So, I found that by moving the datetimepicker `js` to prepend, creating `/custom-typings/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.d.ts` and using `$(this.picker).datetimepicker();` in my code, I have the control working without having to do the `console.log` hack. I also found that I could also remove `/custom-typings` and rely on `npm` to install the typings and everything is kosher still. I still don't know how it knows to refer to it as `datetimepicker` though.

Comment: One last note, I learned that the definition for this picker changes the way you interact with it so the examples for the JS on the site don't work that way. I'll just have to dig through the definition and figure out how to use it the TS way. And thanks again Fabio!

Comment: Oh, and I did have to use the `copyFiles` feature to get the datetimepicker's CSS somewhere I could `<link>` to.